# Catch and save elements in Laravel, not by primaryKey

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get an element from the database, but I can not get it by the FIND method, since FIND only finds it by the primaryKey and what I need is not by my primaryKey. So I did like this:

```
 $user = Pac::find($request->pac_id);
 $element = query()->where('med_cart', $user->pac_id)->get();
 $element->med_obs = $request->med_obs;
 $element->save(); // error
```

Now I need to save this element, however, I can not use the SAVE method, as I believe it is fully connected with FIND and FINDORFAIL (if anyone knows, explain to me which methods I can use the SAVE method).

How can I save them the way I did? Or is there some other way to do it?

Because I need to get the element with a data other than the primaryKey and then save it, then I can not use FIND or FINDORFAIL, I think.

Comment: You don't need `Pac::find()`, you need `Pac::where('column', 'value');`. An item in the database is called a **record**, not *element*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `->find()` returns an Eloquent [`Model`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) instance and you can then call `->save()` on the model instance.

You're using `->get()` which returns a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html).

To update your query (*that may target one or more entries*) just perform the update statement directly from the QueryBuilder by replacing `->get()` with `->update(['med_obs' => $request->med_obs])`.

Be aware that when doing this you are now using Fluent queries, instead of eloquent. This means that any logic you may have defined in the `boot` function of your model is not evaluated.

If you are certain that you only have a single result you can append `->first()` to your query, which will return a Model of the first result that matches your `->where` clause. You can then call `->save()` on it:

```
$user = Pac::find($request->pac_id);
$element = query()->where('med_cart', $user->pac_id)->first();
$element->med_obs = $request->med_obs;
$element->save();
```